# Incorrect format of data in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have made a HTML and tried all combinations.i am not able to get proper formatting.
The last column goes beyond table width.

Also, I have attached the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

Please find below code  and suggest what is wrong here:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <table id="Table_Upper" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="1000" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tr>
          <td width="150"></td>
          <td>
            <table id="Table_calc" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="102">
              <tr>
                <div width="150" class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="250px">Total numbers of amortization</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest rate %</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="250px">Amortization per year</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest per year</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>

              </tr>
            </table>

          </td>
          <td style="width:300px"></td>
          <td>
            <table id="Table_calc" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="102">
              <tr>
                <div width="150" class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="240">Total numbers of amortization</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="240">Interest rate %</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="240">Amortization per year</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>

              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign='top' width="240">Interest per year</td>
                <td>
                  <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
                </td>

              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td style="width:100px"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>


  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:250px" valign="top">
      <table id="Table_OwnersTogether" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="1000" style="table-layout: fixed">


        <tr>
          <th style="width: 100" valign='top'>Income Details</th>


          <th width="70">2018
            <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2019
            <!-- Kalkylränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2020
            <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2021
            <!-- Kalkylränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2022
            <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2023
            <!-- Kalkylränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2024
            <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2025
            <!-- Kalkylränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2026
            <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
          </th>
          <th width="70">2027
            <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
          </th>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td width="100" valign='top'>
            <%=hentlabel("HFA4440")%>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

          <td>
            <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'>
          </td>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason everything is inline and not in a css stylesheet?

Comment: Its old legacy application and has to follow same work style

Comment: i think it has nothing to with last td all td height are same its just overlapping on each other only last one is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `input` elements are simply overlapping one another, and the attempt to set their width is not working because setting the `width` attribute of an `input` element only works for certain types (and does nothing here).

Here's one thing you could do:

change all these lines

```
<input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" ...
```

to this

```
<input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>; width:70px" type="text" ...
```

An alternative, which masks the problem rather than actually fixing it, is to set the overflow to hidden in the table element, like this

```
<table id="Table_OwnersTogether" style="table-layout: fixed; overflow: hidden; width:1000px" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
```

Comment: I am getting this warning .Width is not valid in HTML5.

Comment: quite. Width should be set in css, not as an attribute to the input element. Which is why I rewrote the <input> element to remove the width attribute and added the width:70px in css (which is valid)

Comment: I've edited the <table> element to put the width into css as well, which is preferable.

Comment: Thanks.You are life saver :)

Comment: That's OK. I think there are other issues with the html you posted, but at least this fixes your width issue. A big part of your problem seems to be mixing legacy attributes like `width` with modern css like `table-layout:fixed`. Probably better if possible to switch to css throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is are couple of `<TD>` missing you need to add `<td colspan="2">` in below code

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><div width="150" class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div></td>
</tr>
```

Please check this [JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/zifujux) and see if this is what you need. Below is the compleat code for reference

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                         <td valign="top">
                            <table id="Table_Upper" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="1000" style="table-layout:fixed">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="150" ></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table width=100% id="Table_calc" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="102">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2"><div width="150" class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div></td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="250px">Total numbers of amortization</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest rate %</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="250px">Amortization per year</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="250px">Interest per year</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:300px"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table width=100%  id="Table_calc" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="102">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2"><div width="150"  class="heading">Amortization Calculation</div></td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="240">Total numbers of amortization</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="240">Interest rate %</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="240">Amortization per year</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign='top' width="240">Interest per year</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" style="width: 13px" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:100px"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                                </td>


                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:250px" valign="top">
                            <table id="Table_OwnersTogether" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="1000" style="table-layout: fixed">


                                <tr>
                                    <th style="width: 100" valign='top'>Income Details</th>


                                    <th width="70">2018
                                        <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2019
                                        <!-- Kalkylränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2020
                                        <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2021
                                        <!-- Kalkylränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2022
                                        <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2023
                                        <!-- Kalkylränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2024
                                        <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2025
                                        <!-- Kalkylränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2026
                                        <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
                                    </th>
                                    <th width="70">2027
                                        <!-- Faktiska ränta-->
                                    </th>

                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100" valign='top'><%=hentlabel("HFA4440")%></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                    <td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input readonly style="background-color: <%=slskb_color5%>;" type="text" width="70" name="MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1" value='<%= MAN_KNID_OSS_GROSS_YEARLY_INCOME_HH_1  %>'></td>

                                </tr>

                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>
```